# Fixed size integers with gmp...?

Tags: c++, c, mingw, gmp, 128-bit

I've been trying for days to install GMP library under MINGW. I have been using for weeks `__uint128_t` with gcc under a linux64 bit environment, then ported the same program under GMP and mingw (32 bit version). I used `mpz_class` integers instead of `__uint128_t`. Then I started my new program and...! With `__uint128_t` and 64 bit it takes 16 minutes to complete, with GMP and MINGW it takes 91 HOURS!!!

What should I do to speed up things a bit? Is there any faster way to do 128 bit integer math under a 32 bit environment? I don't need more than 128 bit, so is there any way to tell GMP "ok, I just need 128 bits, keep presicion fixed but please GO FASTER"?

Comment: What operations do you need to do on 128 bits? (`+`, `-`, `<`/`>`, `*`, `/`, something more interesting?)

Comment: 64-bit is supported natively by the compiler. Find code that does 64-bit arithmetic using 32-bit uints and use the principles to implement it for 128 bit uints using 64-bit uints. It'll not be as quick as native 128 bit support (which you might be able to get with e.g. SSE) but it'll probably be faster than libgmp.

Comment: 64 bit may be supported by the compiler, but especially things like division (and modulo) and multiplication can be much faster in a real 64 bit environment (IOW, 64 bit registers, and more of them as well).

Answer (score 3):

No, when you are using an `mpz_t`, you can't limit GMP to fixed-len integers. mpz_t is a struct with lenght of limbs array (allocated; used) and a pointer to actual value which is stored as array of ints (limbs; array of int32 or int64). GMP is ready to expand length of any value when it will grow to big.

You can allocate 128 bits for every mpz_t at init, using `mpz_init2`:

```
 mpz_init2(mpz_t*, bit_number);
```

But the speedup from this is small, there is still data-indirection and length-handling.

You can use limbs directly with switching to  `mpn_` low-level functions:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gmp/manual/html_node/Low-level-Functions.html#Low-level%20Functions

There will be no pointer to limbs (this is good for cache), no easy input/output code; and no automatic limbs size handling (nor auto-expand; nor allocation). You should do all storage by yourself; may be even some carry must be handled manually, but there will be GMP's fast `*`, `/` and `%` operations; you can reconstruct mpz_t for easy input/output with     `mpz_t t;t._mp_size = t._mp_alloc=limb_number;t._mp_d=pointer_to_limb_array`.

Also, you just can use uint128_t if you will switch to 64-bit mingw.

Comment: And using mpz_init2 and allocating 128 bit is going to make it faster..?

Comment: @Matteo he said "But the speedup from this is small."

Comment: @Seth (thank you, but he edited the answer! :D I hadn't seen it before!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) instead, if the Windows machines you're targeting are new enough to ship with 64-bit Windows (e.g. Vista or 7).